# Iron golem fall damage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How many blocks does it take to kill an Iron Golem?

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Iron_golem

Answer (score 2):

Iron Golems are immune to fall damage according to [The Official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Damage#Fall_damage).

I tested this myself and the iron golem took no damage no matter how high I dropped it.